# Importing Image Assets into Android Studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, import, png

I have successfully imported my image assets or app icon into Android Studio for my app but the problem is in the latest version of Android Studio there is a script and sub 'ic_launcher_round.png' folder under res>mipmap which imports icons in the Android Nougat Round Icons Format, now I don't want my icon to be converted or have a round padding which these folder does and removing this folder forces me to remove the scripts from the source file too then only my app icons are successfully build and shown in the Android Emulator, so my question is how can I import my App Icons in the proper and successful way

And removing the unwanted icons results in build errors cause in the source files there is a usage-code for this unwanted icons so when the 'Gradle' syncs and when Android Studio doesn't finds these icons/folder it gives me an error , I mean that particular line of code in the source file(which is automatically generated during 'gradle' build) doesn't find it's supporting files thus interrupts the 'Gradle' Sync!

When I import my App icon via new>image assest the default ic_launcher.png gets replaced and then wehen I execute my app in the emulator the virtual device shows the default android studio icons which is the ic_launcher_round.png so I again imported my image assests(App icon) and this time replaced the ic_launcher_round.png and this time it was executed and the emulator was showing my app icon but with a round padding or oval around it inspite of the fact that my App icon is in the form of a rounded square [My App Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbqvn.png)

[image]

Comment: No removing the unwanted icons results in build errors cause in the source files there is a usage-code for this unwanted icons so when the 'Gradle'  syncs and when Android Studio doesn't finds these icons/folder it gives me an error , I mean that particular line of code in the source file(which is automatically generated during 'gradle' build) doesn't find it's supporting files thus interrupts the 'Gradle' Sync!

Comment: Removing the script from the 'Gradle' results in build errors and Android Studio is warning me not to delete or change anything since this is the source file!